# Excel SUMIF using current row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I've never had to come here for the various Excel conundrums I've had in the past, but this one has me stumped. It has to do with this table :

[image: table screenshot]

I want to get the total amount of assists I have, but ***only*** in games that I have won (Goals For > Goals Against). The total in this table would be 4+2+5+0+2=13.

This has proven tricky, because I want the result of 13 to be returned to a single cell, so referencing the current row during the calculation isn't as easy as having a column of formulas that I can drag down to account for each new row.

I've read answers suggesting VLOOKUP, INDEX(MATCH()), etc. but they seem to be addressing problems similar, but not exactly alike to mine.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` as:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A11>B2:B11)*(C2:C11))
```

See image for reference:

[image]

**EDIT : ______________________________________________________________**

> **`SUMPRODUCT`** function multiplies arrays in formula and returns the sum of those products.

So as per data in the question, formula will be evaluated as follows:

***Step 1:*** ***Calculate (A2:A11>B2:B11)***

This will give you array as:

```
{(A2>B2);(A3>B3);(A4>B4);(A5>B5);(A6>B6);(A7>B7);(A8>B8);(A9>B9);(A10>B10);(A11>B11)}
```

which is

```
{(4>1);(4>1);(1>3);(6>2);(0>4);(2>1);(3>2);(1>4);(2>3);(2>6)}
```

and is equivalent to

```
{TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE}
```

This is same as

```
{1;1;0;1;0;1;1;0;0;0}
```

***Step 2:*** ***Calculate (C2:C11)***

This will give you array as:

```
{4;2;0;5;0;0;2;1;1;2}
```

***Step 3: Calculate (A2:A11>B2:B11)*** * ***(C2:C11)***

This will calculated as:

```
{1;1;0;1;0;1;1;0;0;0}*{4;2;0;5;0;0;2;1;1;2}
```

which is equivalent to

```
{1*4;1*2;0*0;1*5;0*0;1*0;1*2;0*1;0*1;0*2}
```

and will give

```
{4;2;0;5;0;0;2;0;0;0}
```

***Step 4:*** ***Calculate SUMPRODUCT((A2:A11>B2:B11)*(C2:C11))***

This is equal to

```
SUMPRODUCT({4;2;0;5;0;0;2;0;0;0})
```

and will be calculated as

```
4+2+0+5+0+0+2+0+0+0 = 13
```

For details on `SUMPRODUCT` see [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e).

Comment: @ScottCraner it works like a charm! However, I still have no idea HOW it works, and the formula editor isn't too helpful because the entire formula is under the "Array 1" argument. If you could explain what SUMPRODUCT does, I would really appreciate it! But either way, well done.

Comment: @ZachBrown as this is not my answer I will allow Mrig the chance to respond.

Comment: @Mrig Makes perfect sense! The step I was missing in my thought process was the conversion of TRUE and FALSE to 1 and 0. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming "Goals For" is column A "Goals Against" column B and "Assists" column C. I would us an array formula if there isn't a ton of data.

```
{=SUM(IF(A:A>B:B,C:C,0))}
```

Make sure you use `Shift+Ctrl+Enter` to enter the formula since this is an array formula.

Comment: With array formulas it is best practice not to use full column references as they calculate exponentially.